# Десериализация отсутствующего класса. Java

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с таким интересным кейсом: Есть некое пространство(папка, MQ-очередь, топик кафки, в общем - неважно), куда пишется в сериализованом виде Объект Java-класса. При помощи своего листенера я слушаю это пространство. И вытаскиваю данный объект. Есть ли возможность десериализовать или вытащить данные из объекта, при условии что класса данного объекта у меня нет? Как минимум в виде мапы "someFieldName ==> someFieldValue".

Естественно при попытках обычной десириализации ловлю Class not Found. 
 ObjectInputStream.getFiels выдает NotActiveException.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: то есть вытащить "то не знаю что"? В принципе это возможно, но придется копаться в стандартах сериализации java. Как объект сохраняется хорошо описано тут https://habrahabr.ru/post/60317/

Comment: тут уже смотрели? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275201/objectstream-is-there-a-way-to-read-serialized-object-as-properties-map

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй десериализовать к `Object`. А потом с помощью механизма рефлексии вытаскивать поля класса. Например:

```
        P p = new P();

        try(ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                             new FileOutputStream("myStrings.data"))) {
            oos.writeObject(p);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
```

Записал объект `P`.

```
        try(ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                            new FileInputStream("myStrings.data"))) {

            Object someClass = ois.readObject().getClass().newInstance();
            Field[] fields = someClass.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            System.out.println(fields[0].getGenericType() + " " +
                               fields[0].getName() + " = " +
                               fields[0].get(someClass));
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
```

Получу вывод:
`int id = 0`

Таким образом можно получить все поля данного (непонятно какого) класса. Далее можно делать с этим массивом что тебе нужно.

Comment: Как раз таки пытался десириализовать к Object. В этом то вся и суть что даже к Object десериализуется только при наличии класса сериализуемого объекта. Вот пример моего тестового кода:    
    `byte[] payload = message.getPayload(); //мой объект в виде массива байт
bys = new ByteArrayInputStream(payload);
obis = new ObjectInputStream(bys);
Object object = obis.readObject();`
   Выбрасывает java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Comment: На сколько я понял, изучив данный вопрос, что самый главный критерий для класса, который вы получаете, это наличие `implements Serializable`. Если класс реализует этот интерфейс, все будет ок. Если же нет, то выполнении десериалищацию просто невозможно. Так как будет ошибка `java.io.NotSerializableException`.

Comment: К сожалению, большей информацией в данном вопросе я не обладаю. Подсказал, все что знал и понимал сам.